# Matrix multiplying Optimization ( Using Neon simd vs shader )

Tags: c++, matrix, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I am very curious what differences between GLSL/GLSL and NEON

I know GLSL is using GPU cores and NEON is using CPU cores.

However what I am confused is when I multiply a matrix by a matrix using NEON instruction, I am not sure it is a really better way than multiplying a matrix by a matrix in Shader codes because as you know, GPU has much more cores than cpu even if NEON exists to help calculation faster.

Anyone knows what difference between two ways are ?

Comment: This is just your choice anyway, Neon is faster than shader in this case because if you use neon we can use optimized vector calculation not scalar but if you ask about gpgpu it will be more powerful when you need to use much bigger calculation like solving mathematical problems or physics calculations

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty hard to say since you are discussing a CPU instruction set primarily for embedded applications (ARM NEON). This implies to me that you are dealing with an embedded GPU, which may or may not be scalar in nature. Newer GPUs are scalar, but older architectures are vector and embedded architectures are frequently on the older side design wise. So while you know for sure that NEON-based Matrix multiplication is SIMD, on the GLSL end of things it may be scalar or vector depending on the host GPU.

But all this discussion of ***how*** the operations are actually implemented is irrelevant in the grand scheme of things. What really matters is *why* you are performing the matrix multiplication. If it is something that does not vary per-vertex or per-fragment, then you are usually better off doing it on the CPU. Otherwise, even though the GPU may have more functional units, you are wasting computing resources doing the same calculation over and over in parallel.

Your question seems to imply that this is something that could be done once on the CPU and used multiple times during shading, and that would be the better approach to take generally.

Comment: I didn't get your point clearly. Let's comparing two cases If every each frame I multiply two matrices in c++  like mat3 = mat1 x mat2; and it is multiplied by a position vector. This case would be faster than using vertex shader ? like gl_position = mat1 x mat2 x position ? If so could you tell me more details ?